# IR FM Audio Modulator 3.1 MHz Carrier

Tags: led, audio, oscillator, infrared

I'm looking to make a circuit that modulates an audio signal with FM into an IR led. This is going to be a makeshift version of one of [these](https://www.toa.jp/products/wireless_microphones/ir_wireless_system/ir-310m_y.html). I've seen a few FM IR modulators online before, but most of them only operate with a carrier less than 100 kHz.

Could I use a microcontroller like a teensy to do this with their built-in DAC, or would it be better to make an analog circuit?

Any recommendations for places to start?

Comment: Why use 3.1 MHz?

Comment: If you're leaning toward *microcontroller*, then you might look for one that includes ADC (for audio input), numerically-controlled-oscillator (NCO) for FM-able carrier generation - a single-chip solution. Haven't tried this - but I don't see an unsurmountable obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for FM modulation of a carrier with an analog audio signal. My first thought was: Leave it, but these are the options I see. You don't need a sine wave for the IR transmitter. A square wave with reduced duty cycle is fine for IR transmissions. More peak current gives more range at the same average current.

The problem here is the required resolution. If you want to achieve at least 60 dB signal to noise ratio using FM modulation, you need a timer or frequency generator, that runs at 3.1 MHz and where you can control the period or phase in very small steps. The base frequency should be 1 GHz or above, which will be a problem on popular MCUs.
The situation is much better using a carrier of 100 kHz only created from 100 MHz base clock, but digital encoding would have great advantages here. Sending FM encoded 16 bit values is so much easier than analog FM.

You can configure a timer running at the carrier frequency and setup a compare event at half the period. Then modulate the compare event with the audio signal. On each compare event you start a one shot timer to provide the IR pulses. This way you can implement a phase modulation of close to +/- 180 degree, which is an FM modulation as well.

Some DDS ICs offer this phase modulation option as well, they are expensive.

An analog solution with poor 40 dB S/N can easily implemented with a 74HC7046 PLL chip. You provide a 3.1 MHz clock from somewhere and let the PLL lock on this. Then you can add the audio signal to the analog feedback loop of the PLL to create deviations it its output frequency.
The same chip can be used in the receiver. If it has locked on the carrier, the audio signal is visible in the feedback loop.

There are better PLLs or VCOs with lower phase noise than this CMOS chip, it is just an example.

There are, or at least were, dedicated ICs for IR audio links. I think you get far better results using them.